# В laravel 5 НЕ срабатывает в роуте адресс после " / "

Tags: php, laravel

routes:

```
Route::get('/', [
'uses' => 'ProductController@getIndex',
'as'  => 'product.index'
]);

Route::get('/signup', [
'uses' => 'UserController@getSignup',
'as'   => 'user.signup'
]);
```

Стоит laravel 5.2 в файле routes  первый роут срабатывает, а второй нет. НЕ срабатывает в роуте адресс после " / ".
П.С.: UserController подставлял в первый роут-работает!!Только адресс после  " / " не хочет.

Помогите пожалуйста!

UserController, если прописать ТОЛЬКО с " / " ( НЕ '/signup'), срабатывает:

```
Route::get('/signup', [
'uses' => 'UserController@getSignup',
'as'   => 'user.signup'
]);
```

Comment: Сервер как настроен? Запросы все заруливаются на index.php?

Comment: Сервер Apache 2.4 смотрит в папку public, права все открыты. НЕ заруливает только после " / "

Comment: Проверьте список маршрутов, всё ли там ок, ничего ли не пересекается: `php artisan route:list`

Comment: ничего не пересекается....(
там только эти маршруты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, дело было в настройках апача!
Нужно включить rewrite через консоль:

```
 apache2ctl -M | grep -i rew
 sudo a2enmod rewrite
 sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```